# Vertical spacing of framed environment

Tags: spacing, boxes, framed

Here is an MWE that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{3pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fbox{Foo}

\fbox{Foo}

\begin{framed}
  Foo
\end{framed}
\begin{framed}
  Foo
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image: vertical spacing problem]

---

The [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package puts more spacing around its argument than `\fbox` does. I can reduce the "cell padding" to its default by fixing `\FrameSep` but I don't know how to fix the horizontal spacing outside the frame. The documentation is... sparse. I don't read TeX fluently enough to understand `framed.sty` but it's a fairly small file, so I expect is it easy to do...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try mdframed.sty, extending the package framed.sty. You have a better control of parameters. Look at the documentation for all the options (mdframed-doc-en.pdf) [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/).
The parameters to adjust the text inside the box are : innerleftmargin,innerrightmargin, innertopmargin etc. and you have a macro `\mdfsetup` to set all these options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\fbox{Foo}

\fbox{Foo}

\begin{mdframed}
  Foo
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}
  Foo
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: mdframed]

Comment: Very good advice to use [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) instead! Perhaps also add a link to the package on CTAN in your answer. That package is pretty new, perhaps it's not included in everyone's installation.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, you are right but I'm a new user and I have not good reflexes. I hope the link is correct !

Comment: the link is correct! We usually choose package links this way: `http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed`. It's easy to remember and to guess, furthermore it doesn't depend on the path in the tex archive. At least we hope these `pkg` links work longer.

Comment: I think the reason I wasn't using mdframed was because it wasn't installed! I'm more confident than I used to be ab)out installing stuff myself, so I've installed it, and it works perfectly. Word of warning: the `style=1` option has to be a package option. It doesn't work if you call it in `\mdfsetup`. (It makes all your frames disappear.)

Answer (score 8):

`framed` adds spacing according to `\topsep`. Try

```
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
```

to see the effect. To avoid effects to the rest of the document, adjust it locally, i.e. using your own `framed`-like environment which sets that length. Within your own environment you could call:

```
\begin{MakeFramed}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
  \advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}
  ...
\end{MakeFramed}
```

Comment: Thanks! but setting topsep to 0 doesn't quite make the two halves of my MWE identical, it looks like there's still extra spacing in framed.

Comment: Also, setting topsep inside the environment doesn't seem to work... (And I don't really understand what `\advance\hsize-\width` is doing)

Comment: @Seamus: `framed` does a lot more than `\fbox`, internally. If I want it to act the same like `\fbox`, I would just use the latter. You could redefine `\fb@afterframe`, to insert negative space after the box, though it would affect following text.

Comment: I think is dangerous to redefine `\fb@afterframe`. Perhaps, we can (re)define  `\FrameHeightAdjust` (height of frame above baseline at top of page).                                 One remark : framed.sty uses fbox `\providecommand\FrameCommand{%
 \setlength\fboxrule{\FrameRule}\setlength\fboxsep{\FrameSep}%
 \fbox}`
`\@ifundefined{FrameRule}{\newdimen\FrameRule \FrameRule=\fboxrule}{}`
`\@ifundefined{FrameSep} {\newdimen\FrameSep  \FrameSep =3\fboxsep}{}`