# Spacing with framed and mdframed packages

Tags: spacing, framed, mdframed

I have a slight problem with the `framed` package when combined with the `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{simpages}%
{\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \shadowbox}\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{simpages}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{simpages}

Some more text

\end{document}
```

This leads to the following result:

[image: framed example]

As you can see, the vertical space above the items is much larger than the one below - this is what I would like to correct. I've tried to switch to the `mdframed` package [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12711/vertical-spacing-of-framed-environment), but so far unsuccessfully:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv{simpages}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{simpages}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{simpages}

Some more text

\end{document}
```

The result is pretty much the same, only now the shadow effect is missing...

Why is the vertical space above and below the contents of the environment different, and how do I adjust it?

[image: mdframed example]

Comment: You seem to be using an outdated version of `mdframed`; in my system (TeX Live2013) I use `mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed` and the undesired space is not present.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: That might be the case, I'm still on TL 2012 here. However, is there an option to fix the issue with the `framed` package? I rather prefer the shadowed box :-)

Comment: Please see my updated answer; at the end there's one possible workaround using `framed`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here there are two options to produce the shadowed box, one using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), and the other one with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newmdenv[
shadow=true]
{simpages}
\newtcolorbox{tsimpages}{
enhanced,
breakable,
arc=0pt,
outer arc=0pt,
colback=white,
shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{color=black!50,sharp corners},
}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{simpages}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{simpages}
Some more text
\begin{tsimpages}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{tsimpages}
Some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with the `framed` package, making some adjustments so the `parskip` option doesn't interfere:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{simpages}%
{\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\parskip=0pt\parsep=0pt\partopsep=0pt}
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=.5\FrameSep\shadowbox}\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{simpages}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item Baz
\end{itemize}
\end{simpages}
Some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]